# Why in xcode 6 beta Organizer doesn't show Devices tab?

Tags: xcode6

I wonder why xCode 6 Beta the Organizer doesn't contain "Devices" tab?

Anyways, xCode shows that device is connected.

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: I assume you are aware that Devices is now a separate tab. So it appears to be Xcode 6 design question for Apple. I would get myself use to the new design.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

"Devices" now has its own window. Go to "Window" menu then "Devices" or press Shift-Command-2.

Comment: May I vent?  So Apple forced all developers, starting with XCode 4, to use "one window for everything", except "special" windows like the Organizer.  Now they backpedal even further, adding a separate "devices" window?!  I wish they would just admit the failure of the one window paradigm

Comment: I don't really see it as failure. I see it as change. Same thing happened with Apple's idea behind never making a smart phone [bigger than 4 inches.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EY4c2mh15Yk) However the new devices are awesome, and so is change :)

Answer (score 1):

Select Xcode Goto Window > Devices.